# Constructing an adjacency matrix

Tags: c++, graph, maps, dijkstra

I am trying to create a mini world map consisting of 40 cities (40x40 adjacency matrix) that will tell you the shortest distance and path between 2 cities, your vertex (starting city) and your nth city (final city).
Im trying to obtain the correct matrix for this but I'm having a lot of problems getting the right values in each entry of my 40x40 matrix.
Ive initialized the matrix by file reading a text file of the format:
41
0 1 84.4 -999
1 0 84.4 2 107.9 -999
...and so on
where 40 is the graph size (int dimension in my graph class) and first entry of every row being  the first city followed by its adjacent cities and the distance between them. Each row ends with -999.

Here is my matrix initialization code:

```
void Initialize_Graph ()
{
    int city, adj_city; double weight = 0;   //starting at [0][0]
    //dimension size (should be 40)
    ifstream fin("map.txt");
    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "Text file could not be located! Try again." << endl;
    }

    fin >> dimension;
    
    cout<<endl<<"DEBUG*********"<<endl<<dimension<<endl;  //for debugging

    
    Main_Matrix = new double*[dimension]; // n = 40 rows created for weighted matrix
    for (int n = 0; n < dimension; n++)
    {
        Main_Matrix[n] = new double[dimension]; //create a nxn = [40][40] 2d-Matrix for                   
                                                        //our weighted Graph
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < dimension; n++)
    { 

            fin >> city;
            fin >> adj_city;
            
            while ( adj_city != -999)
            {
                fin >> weight; //take in the weight/length of the 
                                               //adjacent cities' route.

    Main_Matrix[city][adj_city] = weight; //now plug in this weight value into the 
                                             //respective position of city -> adj city on our 
                                             //matrix.
                                                          //e.g.: at start: [venice][venice] = 0 as we previously set, after this: [venice][lyon] = 289.7 
//(kilometers)                                              
                fin >> adj_city; //repeat process 
                //until text file reads -999
            }
      }
    
            fin.close();
    }
```

Here is my text file that should give a good idea of how the weighted adjacency matrix should look like:
[My Map's text file that should determine my matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QCZ3.png)

Here is what my matrix ends up being:
[My result (wrong outlandish values)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDzar.jpg)

minimum reproduced example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cfloat>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;


class Weighted_Graph
{
    private:
        double** Main_Matrix; 
        double* lengths;
        int* pathways;
        int dimension;  //matrix dimension (40x40 for this assingment.)
    public:
    Weighted_Graph () //default constructor
        {
        Main_Matrix=NULL;
        pathways=NULL;
        lengths=NULL;
        dimension= 0;
        }
        
void Initialize_Graph ()
    {
    int city, adj_city; double weight = 0;   //starting at [0][0]
    //dimension size (should be 40)
    ifstream fin("map.txt");
    if (!fin)
        cout << "Text file could not be located! Try again." << endl;
    fin >> dimension;
    Main_Matrix = new double*[dimension]; // n = 40 rows created for weighted matrix
    for (int n = 0; n < dimension; n++)
        Main_Matrix[n] = new double[dimension]; //create a nxn = [40][40] 2d-Matrix for our weighted Graph

    for (int n = 0; n < dimension; n++)
    { 
            fin >> city;
            fin >> adj_city;
            
            while ( adj_city != -999)
                {
                    fin >> weight; 
                    Main_Matrix[city][adj_city] = weight; 
                    fin >> adj_city; //repeat process 
                    //until text file reads -999
                }
    }
            fin.close();
            
     for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
            {
                cout<<Main_Matrix[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

}; 

int main ()
{
    Weighted_Graph World;
    World.Initialize_Graph();

}
```

my map text file that is bein imported can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-W_0pkxDQCC1lKrofKTzXf2HZlDH1EnA/view?usp=sharing

Im very sorry if im still not following the correct method and format of posting queries on stack as im new to the site and trying my best to do right!! :(

Comment: `Main_Matrix = new double*[dimension];`  This is extremely odd!  Does it even compile?  You need to declare the type!  Perhaps it is a global?  In which case you need to show us your entire code, not just a fragment.

Comment: I am guessing from your code that you have not been writing C++ code for long.  That's OK, but I would suggest you start with attempting something simpler and then work up to implementing Dijsktra.

Comment: Don't use pointers and `new[]`. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: so this variable is basically double ** Main_Matrix; (for creating a 2d dynamic matrix of type double) it does compile like i showed in the image and in most entries of the 40x40 matrix I get the right values placed - but in certain entries this code puts in outlandish values as u can see and I'm so very confused why and over how to fix it :(

Comment: my assignment requires me to use pointers and dynamic arrays or else i'd use vectors

Comment: If you want help, then you have to show your entire code, not just a fragment.  Variables are not "basicaly" something or other.  You have to declare them as one thing or another.

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: So it is an assignment.  The person assigning this should respect your ability level and give you detailed instructions on how to do this.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: alright, how can i show the entire code? i think posting your whole code in a question gets it marked as spam, no?

Comment: We don't need all your code, we need [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Make it `Main_Matrix[n] = new double[dimension]{};`. The pair of braces ensures the new array is initialized with zeros. Without those braces, it's uninitialized, containing random garbage; which is likely what you observe.

Comment: hey evg, i edited the post to create a minimum reproduced example please check it out and let me know

Comment: Thankyou so much Igor!! You fixed my matrix representation problem!!! The matrix is showing correctly now.